# How to change Payment Methods on PWA Suite?

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, magento2.4, pwa-studio, react

I have installed the PWA suite on my local machine.

I have enabled COD and Check / Money order Payment methods. But Why these methods are not showing on the checkout page. Pay with Card only displaying!

[image: Only show in that..]

I try with Cach flush and setup upgrade. Not anything change. What is the solution? I need to create custom modules or can buy customer payment module. How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot, it seems that you are trying to change the payment method in BILLING INFORMATION section in the PWA Studio

For now, By default payment integration added was Braintree for the other payment method you have to customize it as per your preference.

You can refer the imported component `BraintreeDropin` in the `venia-ui/lib/components/Checkout/paymentsFormItems.js`